# How to use aggregations with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search to create a search filter and I need to find all the values saved in the database of the "cambio" column without repeating the values.

The values are saved as follows: "Manual de 5 marchas" or "Manual de 6 marchas"....

I created this query to return all saved values:

```
GET /crawler10/crawler-vehicles10/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cambio"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the returned values they look like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "my_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 2613,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "de",
               "doc_count": 2755
            },
            {
               "key": "marchas",
               "doc_count": 2714
            },
            {
               "key": "manual",
               "doc_count": 2222
            },
            {
               "key": "modo",
               "doc_count": 1097
            },
            {
               "key": "5",
               "doc_count": 1071
            },
            {
               "key": "d",
               "doc_count": 1002
            },
            {
               "key": "n",
               "doc_count": 1002
            },
            {
               "key": "automática",
               "doc_count": 935
            },
            {
               "key": "com",
               "doc_count": 919
            },
            {
               "key": "6",
               "doc_count": 698
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregations are based on the mapping type of the saved field. The field type for `cambio` seems to be set to `analyzed`(by default). Please create an index with the mapping `not_analyzed` for your field `cambio`.

You can create the index with a `PUT` request as below (if your ES version is less than 5) and then you will need to re-index your data in the `crawler10` index.

```
PUT crawler10/_mapping/
{
  "mappings": {
    "crawler-vehicles10": {
      "properties": {
        "cambio": {
          "type": "string"
          "index": "not_analyzed"

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For ES v5 or greater

```
PUT crawler10/_mapping/
{
  "mappings": {
    "crawler-vehicles10": {
      "properties": {
        "cambio": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```